# Beginner Java/Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm taking a class and I'm stuck. The assignment is to take an existing app that saves twitter searches and add a filter option. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to add a text control (either a button or a listview/expandablelistview) and populate the filter options using an array but I can't get that to work.

I'm using eclipse and programming for android 2.3.3 (because that's what the book says to do)

Please point me in the right direction.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <!-- tableRow0 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/queryEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:hint="@string/queryPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow1 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/filExpandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ExpandableListView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tagEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/tagPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/save" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow2 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taggedSearchesTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/taggedSearches"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow3 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/queryScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/queryTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow4 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearTagsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="@string/clearTags" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
```

**Java**

```
// main (and only) Activity class for the Favorite Twitter Searches app
public class FavoriteTwitterSearches extends Activity 
{
   private SharedPreferences savedSearches; // user's favorite searches
   private TableLayout queryTableLayout; // shows the search buttons
   private EditText queryEditText; // where the user enters queries
   private EditText tagEditText; // where the user enters a query's tag

   // called when the activity is first created
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call the superclass version
      setContentView(R.layout.main); // set the layout

      // get the SharedPreferences that contains the user's saved searches 
      savedSearches = getSharedPreferences("searches", MODE_PRIVATE);

      // get a reference to the queryTableLayout
      queryTableLayout = 
         (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.queryTableLayout);

      // get references to the two EditTexts  
      queryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
      tagEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagEditText);

      // register listeners for the Save and Clear Tags Buttons
      Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
      Button clearTagsButton = 
        (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearTagsButton);
      clearTagsButton.setOnClickListener(clearTagsButtonListener);


      refreshButtons(null); // add previously saved searches to GUI
   } // end method onCreate

   // recreate search tag and edit Buttons for all saved searches;
   // pass null to create all the tag and edit Buttons.
   private void refreshButtons(String newTag) 
   {
      // store saved tags in the tags array
      String[] tags = 
         savedSearches.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]); 
      Arrays.sort(tags, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // sort by tag

      // if a new tag was added, insert in GUI at the appropriate location
      if (newTag != null)
      {
         makeTagGUI(newTag, Arrays.binarySearch(tags, newTag));
      } // end if
      else // display GUI for all tags
      {         
         // display all saved searches
         for (int index = 0; index < tags.length; ++index)
            makeTagGUI(tags[index], index);
      } // end else
   } // end method refreshButtons

   // add new search to the save file, then refresh all Buttons
   private void makeTag(String query, String tag)
   {
      // originalQuery will be null if we're modifying an existing search
      String originalQuery = savedSearches.getString(tag, null);

      // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to store new tag/query pair
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
      preferencesEditor.putString(tag, query); // store current search
      preferencesEditor.apply(); // store the updated preferences

      // if this is a new query, add its GUI
      if (originalQuery == null) 
         refreshButtons(tag); // adds a new button for this tag
   } // end method makeTag

   // add a new tag button and corresponding edit button to the GUI
   private void makeTagGUI(String tag, int index)
   {
      // get a reference to the LayoutInflater service
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      // inflate new_tag_view.xml to create new tag and edit Buttons
      View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view, null);

      // get newTagButton, set its text and register its listener
      Button newTagButton = 
         (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newTagButton);
      newTagButton.setText(tag); 
      newTagButton.setOnClickListener(queryButtonListener); 

      // get newEditButton and register its listener
      Button newEditButton = 
         (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newEditButton); 
      newEditButton.setOnClickListener(editButtonListener);

      Button newDelButton = 
                 (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newDelbutton); 
              newDelButton.setOnClickListener(delButtonListener);

      // add new tag and edit buttons to queryTableLayout
      queryTableLayout.addView(newTagView, index);
   } // end makeTagGUI

   // remove all saved search Buttons from the app
   private void clearButtons()
   {
      // remove all saved search Buttons
      queryTableLayout.removeAllViews();
   } // end method clearButtons

   // create a new Button and add it to the ScrollView
   public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // create tag if both queryEditText and tagEditText are not empty
         if (queryEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&
            tagEditText.getText().length() > 0)
         {
            makeTag(queryEditText.getText().toString(), 
               tagEditText.getText().toString());
            queryEditText.setText(""); // clear queryEditText
            tagEditText.setText(""); // clear tagEditText

            // hide the soft keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
               Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
               tagEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);  
         } // end if
         else // display message asking user to provide a query and a tag
         {
            // create a new AlertDialog Builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
               new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteTwitterSearches.this);

            builder.setTitle(R.string.missingTitle); // title bar string

            // provide an OK button that simply dismisses the dialog
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null); 

            // set the message to display
            builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage);

            // create AlertDialog from the AlertDialog.Builder
            AlertDialog errorDialog = builder.create();
            errorDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
         } // end else
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // clears all saved searches
   public OnClickListener clearTagsButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // create a new AlertDialog Builder
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteTwitterSearches.this);

         builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); // title bar string

         // provide an OK button that simply dismisses the dialog
         builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.erase,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
               {
                  clearButtons(); // clear all saved searches from the map

                  // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to clear searches
                  SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = 
                     savedSearches.edit();

                  preferencesEditor.clear(); // remove all tag/query pairs
                  preferencesEditor.apply(); //  the changes
               } // end method onClick
            } // end anonymous inner class
         ); // end call to method setPositiveButton

         builder.setCancelable(true);
         builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

         // set the message to display
         builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

         // create AlertDialog from the AlertDialog.Builder
         AlertDialog confirmDialog = builder.create();
         confirmDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // load selected search in a web browser
   public OnClickListener queryButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get the query
         String buttonText = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
         String query = savedSearches.getString(buttonText, "");

         // create the URL corresponding to the touched Button's query
         String urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL) + query;

         // create an Intent to launch a web browser    
         Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse(urlString));                      

         startActivity(webIntent); // execute the Intent
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // edit selected search
   public OnClickListener editButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get all necessary GUI components
         TableRow buttonTableRow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
         Button searchButton = 
            (Button) buttonTableRow.findViewById(R.id.newTagButton);

         String tag = searchButton.getText().toString();

         // set EditTexts to match the chosen tag and query
         tagEditText.setText(tag);
         queryEditText.setText(savedSearches.getString(tag, ""));
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class
   public OnClickListener delButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get all necessary GUI components
         TableRow buttonTableRow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
         queryTableLayout.removeView(buttonTableRow);
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class
} // end class FavoriteTwitterSearches
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working. I used a spinner and coded the array into the strings.xml file. I found some tutorials on how to pass the spinner choice from to a variable and then played with making it work for about a day.

It isn't pretty but it works.

I would still greatly appreciate any pointers that anyone might be willing to provide.

Here is my updated main.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <!-- tableRow0 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/queryEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:hint="@string/queryPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow1 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/filterEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tagEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/tagPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/save" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow2 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taggedSearchesTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/taggedSearches"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow3 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/queryScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/queryTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- tableRow4 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearTagsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="@string/clearTags" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
<!--
```

and my updated java

```
// FavoriteTwitterSearches.java
// Stores Twitter search queries and tags for easily opening them 
// in a browser.
package com.deitel.favoritetwittersearches;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

// main (and only) Activity class for the Favorite Twitter Searches app
public class FavoriteTwitterSearches extends Activity 
{
   private SharedPreferences savedSearches; // user's favorite searches
   private TableLayout queryTableLayout; // shows the search buttons
   private EditText queryEditText; // where the user enters queries
   private EditText tagEditText; // where the user enters a query's tag
   private EditText filterEditText;
   private String filtered;
   private String filter;
   private String filtext;

   // called when the activity is first created
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call the superclass version
      setContentView(R.layout.main); // set the layout

      // get the SharedPreferences that contains the user's saved searches 
      savedSearches = getSharedPreferences("searches", MODE_PRIVATE);

      // get a reference to the queryTableLayout
      queryTableLayout = 
         (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.queryTableLayout);


      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filterSpinner);
      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.filters, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

      final Spinner filterSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filterSpinner);

      filterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                filter = filterSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                                        }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });  

        //get references to the two EditTexts  
      queryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
      tagEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagEditText);
      filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);

      // register listeners for the Save and Clear Tags Buttons
      Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
      Button clearTagsButton = 
        (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearTagsButton);
      clearTagsButton.setOnClickListener(clearTagsButtonListener);


      refreshButtons(null); // add previously saved searches to GUI
   } // end method onCreate

   // recreate search tag and edit Buttons for all saved searches;
   // pass null to create all the tag and edit Buttons.
   private void refreshButtons(String newTag) 
   {
      // store saved tags in the tags array
      String[] tags = 
         savedSearches.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]); 
      Arrays.sort(tags, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // sort by tag

      // if a new tag was added, insert in GUI at the appropriate location
      if (newTag != null)
      {
         makeTagGUI(newTag, Arrays.binarySearch(tags, newTag));
      } // end if
      else // display GUI for all tags
      {         
         // display all saved searches
         for (int index = 0; index < tags.length; ++index)
            makeTagGUI(tags[index], index);
      } // end else
   } // end method refreshButtons

   // add new search to the save file, then refresh all Buttons
   private void makeTag(String query, String tag, String filt)
   {
      // originalQuery will be null if we're modifying an existing search
      String originalQuery = savedSearches.getString(tag, null);

      if(filt != null)
      {
      query = query + filt;}
      else
      {query = query;}

      // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to store new tag/query pair
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
      preferencesEditor.putString(tag, query); // store current search
      preferencesEditor.apply(); // store the updated preferences

      // if this is a new query, add its GUI
      if (originalQuery == null) 
         refreshButtons(tag); // adds a new button for this tag
   } // end method makeTag

   // add a new tag button and corresponding edit button to the GUI
   private void makeTagGUI(String tag, int index)
   {
      // get a reference to the LayoutInflater service
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      // inflate new_tag_view.xml to create new tag and edit Buttons
      View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view, null);

      // get newTagButton, set its text and register its listener
      Button newTagButton = 
         (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newTagButton);
      newTagButton.setText(tag); 
      newTagButton.setOnClickListener(queryButtonListener); 

      // get newEditButton and register its listener
      Button newEditButton = 
         (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newEditButton); 
      newEditButton.setOnClickListener(editButtonListener);

      Button newDelButton = 
                 (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newDelbutton); 
              newDelButton.setOnClickListener(delButtonListener);

      // add new tag and edit buttons to queryTableLayout
      queryTableLayout.addView(newTagView, index);
   } // end makeTagGUI

   // remove all saved search Buttons from the app
   private void clearButtons()
   {
      // remove all saved search Buttons
      queryTableLayout.removeAllViews();
   } // end method clearButtons

   // create a new Button and add it to the ScrollView
   public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
          if(filterEditText.getText().length() > 0)
            {
            filtered = filter + "%3A" + filterEditText.getText().toString();}
          else
          {filtered = "";}


          {
         // create tag if both queryEditText and tagEditText are not empty
         if (queryEditText.getText().length() > 0 &&
            tagEditText.getText().length() > 0)

            makeTag(queryEditText.getText().toString(), 
               tagEditText.getText().toString(),
               filtered);

            queryEditText.setText(""); // clear queryEditText
            tagEditText.setText(""); // clear tagEditText 
            filterEditText.setText("");

            // hide the soft keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
               Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
               tagEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);  
         } // end if
          // display message asking user to provide a query and a tag
         {
            // create a new AlertDialog Builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
               new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteTwitterSearches.this);

            builder.setTitle(R.string.missingTitle); // title bar string

            // provide an OK button that simply dismisses the dialog
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null); 

            // set the message to display
            builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage);

            // create AlertDialog from the AlertDialog.Builder
            AlertDialog errorDialog = builder.create();
            errorDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
         } // end else
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // clears all saved searches
   public OnClickListener clearTagsButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // create a new AlertDialog Builder
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteTwitterSearches.this);

         builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); // title bar string

         // provide an OK button that simply dismisses the dialog
         builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.erase,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
               {
                  clearButtons(); // clear all saved searches from the map

                  // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to clear searches
                  SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = 
                     savedSearches.edit();

                  preferencesEditor.clear(); // remove all tag/query pairs
                  preferencesEditor.apply(); //  the changes
               } // end method onClick
            } // end anonymous inner class
         ); // end call to method setPositiveButton

         builder.setCancelable(true);
         builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

         // set the message to display
         builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

         // create AlertDialog from the AlertDialog.Builder
         AlertDialog confirmDialog = builder.create();
         confirmDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // load selected search in a web browser
   public OnClickListener queryButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get the query
         String buttonText = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
         String query = savedSearches.getString(buttonText, "");

         // create the URL corresponding to the touched Button's query
         String urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL) + query;

         // create an Intent to launch a web browser    
         Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse(urlString));                      

         startActivity(webIntent); // execute the Intent
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class

   // edit selected search
   public OnClickListener editButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get all necessary GUI components
         TableRow buttonTableRow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
         Button searchButton = 
            (Button) buttonTableRow.findViewById(R.id.newTagButton);

         String tag = searchButton.getText().toString();

         // set EditTexts to match the chosen tag and query
         tagEditText.setText(tag);
         queryEditText.setText(savedSearches.getString(tag, ""));
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class
   public OnClickListener delButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // get all necessary GUI components
         TableRow buttonTableRow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
         queryTableLayout.removeView(buttonTableRow);
      } // end method onClick
   }; // end OnClickListener anonymous inner class
} // end class FavoriteTwitterSearches
```